# Is "SELECT TOP 1" really the best way to get a single result when you expect a single result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Whenever I expect a single result that I need to store in a variable I do something like

```
DECLARE @id INT = SELECT TOP 1 [Id] FROM [Stuff] WHERE [Stuff].[Name] = 'Harry';
```

because SQL Server complains if I do

```
DECLARE @id INT = SELECT [Id] FROM [Stuff] WHERE [Stuff].[Name] = 'Harry';
```

***even if it is guaranteed for there to be at most 1 result*** (because, for example, `[Name]` has a `UNIQUE` constraint).

I'm wondering if there's a more proper way of doing that. For example, in C# LINQ there is `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`, like

```
var id = context.Stuff.Single()?.Name;
```

which is more expressive.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is not valid.  This should work if there is at most one row:

```
DECLARE @id INT = (SELECT [Id] FROM [Stuff] WHERE [Stuff].[Name] = 'Harry');
```

You can add the `TOP 1` if you just want to be extra, extra sure not to get a run-time error.

Remember:  subqueries always need their own parentheses.

Answer (score -1):

Ditto what Gordon said about the parenthesis. Now consider the following SQL and note my comments:

```
-- create table with one 'harry'
DECLARE @stuff TABLE (id int identity, name varchar(100));
INSERT @stuff VALUES ('harry');

-- this will succeed, SQL will NOT complain
DECLARE @id int = (SELECT id FROM @stuff WHERE name = 'harry')

-- add another 'harry'
INSERT @stuff VALUES ('harry');

-- this will fail because the subquery returns 2 rows
DECLARE @ids int = (SELECT id FROM @stuff WHERE name = 'harry');
```

Keep in mind that, without an accompanying ORDER BY clause, the results of a TOP statement are not guaranteed to always be the same.

Answer (score -1):

if you are sure that your query will return only one record , you can use :

> DECLARE @id INT
>
> SELECT @id = [Id] FROM [Stuff] WHERE [Stuff].[Name] = 'Harry';